# Probability without knowing how many n cases there are

Tags: probability

So basically this a  followup from a question I did before. So we got 0.25 as the probability of John getting late to work each day, and we assume today is day 1. And the question is what's the probability of John reaching work late the second day after day 3.

So I tried calculating the probability of reaching work late once in the first 3 days, that is 0.421875. But now I'm stuck to how should I proceed for the second time John gets late to work after these 3 days.

Comment: link to that previous question, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The odds of John *never* being late after day three is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac 3 4}^n = 0$.  So we can safely assume he'll be late *some* day after day 3.

That day will be the second day if he is only late once in the first 3 days.  That day will be the first day if his is never late in the first 3 days.  If that day is the first day then the second day will also be after day three.

So the probably that he will be late for the second day after day 3 is the probability that he was late at most once in the first three days.

Prob 2nd day after 3 = Prob late at most once before 3 = Prob never late in first 3 days + Prob late exactly once in three days = ${\frac 3 4}^3 + {\frac 3 4}^2{\frac 1 4}*3 = 2*{\frac 3 4}^3 = 27/32$.

Comment: I'm failing to understand why the probability of getting late to work the second time after day 3 is the probability of being late at most once before day 3, i mean if John's only late the second time at his 10th day wouldn't we have to calculate all the probability and combinations of being late, changing the days in wich John was late thus changing the probability?     But the answer you gave is indeed correct.

Comment: We assume John is going to eventually be late many more times during the rest of his life.  It might be day 4, it might be day 10004.  But it's going to happen sooner or later.  We don't care if he's late on day 4, or day 10, or day 10004.  He will be late sometime.  We just need to know if the second time will be after or before day 3.  If it's after day 3, then he has been at late at most once in the first 3 days.

Comment: Ahhh, I get it now. Thanks for the easy explanation, really gratefull!!! I was making it harder than it was.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are asking the probability of John being late no more than once in the first three days. Since they are disjoint events you can calculate it by summing the probability of being late exactly one time and exactly zero times which is $0.75^3$